# Django - exclude from queryset if every related model meets a condition

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Given two models:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
   ...


class Topping(models.Model):
    on_pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='toppings')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    spicy = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

How can I exclude all Pizzas where "spicy" is set to "False" for every topping?

So, I'd like to have a queryset of Pizzas where every Pizza has at least one spicy topping on it.

Thanks!

Comment: As some answers have already been posted, I'll make a comment about your Pizza-Topping relation. You should change it to a `ManyToManyField`, so you can relate it to many `Pizza`s and avoid duplicating `Topping`s for each `Pizza`. Just take a look a [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships) example in the docs. It will also make more sense if you add the relation to the `Pizza` model

Comment: Yes, you're right. I just picked this example to illustrate my question, it's not my production code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe

```
Pizza.objects.filter(toppings__spicy=True).distinct()
```

?

Answer (score 4):

```
Pizza.objects.filter(toppings__spicy=True).distinct()
```